# Keep A button highlighted when clicked Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I have an application that needs somewhere a button to stay highlighted when pressed. This button should stay highlighted when pressed to inform the users that the specific page is added to favorites. And can be unpressed.
Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just keep an image for the Button for Highlighted state like this.

```
[myBtn setImage:@"highlightedImage.png" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Now, in the method for button check for highlighted version and normal version

```
-(IBAction) startWorkoutClicked:(id)sender
{
     if(btnStart.highlighted)
     {
         btnStart.highlighted = NO; //btn changes to normal state
     }
     else
     {
         btnStart.highlighted = YES; //btn changes to highlighted state 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Question: does this solution still allow the app to automatically recognize the retina versions of the image? (i.e. "highlightedImage@2x.png")
Or would we have to nest another if/else to account for it?

Comment: Yes this would handle the retina images as well. Actually you never have to handle retina images. This is always managed by iOS and it depends on which device it is running on.

Comment: Sorry to jump in on here where would I put the first part of this code?

Comment: @DanDavies wherever you wrote the code to initialize your button. Or if the button is in xib, then write it in viewdidload or any common function you made for making UI changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalState.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedState.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedState.png"] forState:UIControlStateSHighlighted];
```

Set this image preferences and whenever you want call

```
 [yourButton setSelected:YES];
```

which will change your button to highlighted state. You can change it to normal by doing

```
 [yourButton setSelected:NO];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

All is good with the above answer , apart from the typo, which could lead to problems..
UIControlStateSHighlighted should be UIControlStateHighlighted

there are more examples here

http://www.guyford.co.uk/showpage.php?id=279&page=XCode_IPhone_/_IPad_Development_-_Highlighting_a_Button_and_setting_its_image.

Comment: Thank you for your response .. i took notice of it as soon as i started implementing :) but thank you for your contribution